# Resource management with Lua integration

Tags: scripting, lua, resource-management

I have a questions about how to better implement resource management when integrating with Lua. I have an entity system that has gameplay logic done in Lua. One of the design points was that I wanted to simplify the script code as much as possible. To that end, things like sprites and sounds are generic "resource" handles (currently just integers) that are referenced, e.g.

```
self.image = resource("/foo/baz.png")
self.hurtSound = resource("/foo/bar.mp3")
...
play(self.hurtSound)
```

This works well, but I don't know when (from the native code side) it is safe to delete a resource because a Lua object could be holding on to it. I don't have "levels" where there are convenient "load/unload" points, so I'm wondering how I might safely achieve this without making the Lua code have to do anything complicated with resources. Essentially, I want garbage collection for unused resources. I'm not a Lua expert, so I'm sure there is some feature of the language that could implement such a behavior.

My requirement is that I should be able to copy handles around safely, e.g. do not need to call `resource()` twice to do some kind of "obvious" reference counting. Similarly, if `resource()` is called *n* times, but at least 1 reference is valid, then the resource should not be unloaded; i.e. simply because one value was __gc'd, doesn't mean that all of them should be invalidated.

The native code implements the resource cache and simply needs to be informed when it would be *safe* to unload something (even if it doesn't unload it immediately).

Any Lua experts ran into similar sort of situations? What did you do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I always make resources be referenced by userdata so I can:
 Know what I'm accessing in the native code side (I could use a pointer and some kind of mambo jambo to do that but that is subject to another topic) and add it to the registry and in that way creating a reference to it that the garbage collector won't touch.

Refer to Lua registry section [1](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#3.5)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know what the registry is, but I'm not looking to ignore garbage collection, I'm looking to leverage it. If you can explain how your solution would solve my case then I would appreciate it.

Comment: Integers aren't garbage collected only lua objects are. You must provide some context to it so you can acomplish what you are trying to do.